# WYSIWYG Editor media url not working in magento 2.4.0

Tags: image, backend, media, magento2.4.2

Add this code WYSIWYG Editor

```
<p><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/menu/test.jpg"}}" alt=""></p>
```

but it's not working in magento 2.4.0

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider
 */
protected $filterContent;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterContent
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterContent
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->filterContent = $filterContent;
}

/**
 * Get filter content
 * @param  string $content
 * @return string
 */
public function getFilterContent($content)
{
    return $this->filterContent->getPageFilter()->filter($content);
}
```

https://prnt.sc/10us8xa

https://prnt.sc/10us96r

Let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: which file code update? And this issue is face megamenu  WYSIWYG Editor.

Comment: where do you show the image? Which is added in WYSIWYG editor.